# JS how to dynamically populate a second date picker with minDate of the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I populate 2 date pickers? The second date picker has to have at least the value of first date picker.This is my code right now:

```
selector.dtmDlgLimitFrom.attr('readonly', true).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: dateToday,
    yearRange: "0:+100"
});   
selector.dtmDlgLimtTo.attr('readonly', true).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: selector.dtmDlgLimitFrom.datepicker("getDate"),
    yearRange: "0:+100"
});
```

Comment: There is no mention of a specific problem with the code shown

Comment: is not working right now

Comment: define *"not working"*. Errors thrown? Take a few minutes to review [ask]

Comment: right now using the code above it just sets my second date picker to a min value of today.. witch is the minDate of the first. I want to have a dynamic change on my second

Comment: ok... so that's not what was originally asked. Please update question on what it is you actually are trying to achieve and what the criteria are. You will need to use the events api of plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set on "onSelect" event to your first datepicker to set the min date in the second one.

onSelect event will be populated when any date is selected in the datepicker.

Use .dtpicker("option") to set the mindate in the datepicker dynamically.

```
$("#idOfFirstDtPicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    yearRange: "0:+100",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("#idOfSecondDtPicker").datepicker('option', 'minDate', $("#idOfFirstDtPicker").datepicker("getDate"));
    }
});   
$("#idOfSecondDtPicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "0:+100"
});
```

Here, if you want to set today as default mindate for the second datepicker, then you can set mindate property directly there too, as we did for first one.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following to set the min date of second date selector:

```
 minDate: $("#idoffirstdateselector").datepicker("getDate") });
```

e.g.

```
selector.dtmDlgLimtTo.attr('readonly', true).datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     minDate: $("#idoffirstdateselector").datepicker("getDate") }),
     yearRange: "0:+100"
});
```

`idoffirstdateselector` is id of the first date selector.

**Edit**

You can try to set the mindate in onselect of firstdate picker.

```
selector.dtmDlgLimitFrom.attr('readonly', true).datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     minDate: dateToday,
     yearRange: "0:+100",
     onSelect: function(date){
         var date2 = $('#idoffirstdateselector').datepicker('getDate');
         $('#idofseconddateselector').datepicker('option', 'minDate',   date2);      
     }
});
```

Comment: I tried this one already, is it in my code on my second date picker.

Comment: @AndreiChivu then you can also try to set the mindate in onselect of firstdate picker